# Use if(select Count(*) from table) > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server to do some practice and I am trying to use this stored procedure to execute data and insert into table, I don't know why it doesn't insert into table and the record doesn't exist in the table, does any expert know how to solve it?

Query:

```
USE [dbTest]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertPerson]
    @Id varchar(50),
    @Name varchar(50),
    @PhoneNumber varchar(50),
    @Address varchar(50),
    @StartDate datetime

AS

    Create Table #tmpPersonList
    (
        Id varchar(50),
        name varchar(50),
        phoneNumber varchar(50),
        address varchar(50),
        startdate datetime
    )

    Truncate Table #tmpPersonList
    Insert Into #tmpPersonList
    values(@Id, @Name, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @StartDate)

BEGIN
    
    If (Select Count(*) from #tmpPersonList where Id not in (select PersonID from tblPerson)) > 0
    begin
        print 'Found New Record'
        Insert Into tblPerson(PersonID, Name, PhoneNumber, Address, StartDate) 
        Select Id, name, phoneNumber, address, startDate
        From #tmpPersonList
        where Id not in (select PersonID from tblPerson)
        
    End
    else 
    Begin
        print 'Exists Record'
        Return
    End

End
```

Comment: how does the code that calls your procedure look? also, most of the code can be rewritten as `insert into sometable (id, b, c) select @id, @b, @c where not exists(select 1 from sometable where id = @id)`

Comment: FYI, if you have `CREATE`d the table in the prior statement then `TRUNCATE`ing it is completely redundant; the table is already completely empty.

Comment: It would probably make more sense for `PersonID` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, @siggemannen, then the OP *can't* insert a duplicate row and then the `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` can go too; the OP can just `INSERT` straight into the table `tblPerson` and if it's a duplicate an error will be raised about said duplicate key value.

Comment: but what does `if (select Count(*) from table) > 0` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the entire body of your stored procedure could just be replaced with:

```
insert into tblPerson (Id, [Name], PhoneNumber, [Address], StartDate)
select @Id, @Name, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @StartDate
where not exists (select * from tblPerson where Id = @Id)
```

Comment: what does `if (select Count(*) from table) > 0` mean?

Comment: @user21834984 - not sure why this comment is on my answer, as that code doesn't appear anywhere in the example I've given. However, the `SELECT` statement you'd given will return 0 if there are no rows in `table`, otherwise it will return the number of rows, so the `IF` statement will be true if the table has rows in it, and false if the table is empty.

Comment: ok thank you very much